# Returning an Object that contains a List member in WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, datacontract

I have the follow classes in my Shared.DataContracts DLL

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
{
   [DataMember]
   public int Group { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public List<TestClassTwo> Member { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TestClassTwo
{
   [DataMember]
   public long MessageId { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public RequestOpType ResultType { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "RequestOperationType")]
public enum RequestOpType
{
   [EnumMember]
   Add,
   [EnumMember]
   Delete,
   [EnumMember]
   Update,
   [EnumMember]
   Retrieve,
   [EnumMember]
   Search
}
```

My service contract is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IConnectorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PustRequestToWorkBuffer(TestClass test); 
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ConnectorService : IConnectorService
{
    public void PustRequestToWorkBuffer(TestClass test)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

When I try to add the following as a Service Reference to one of my projects I always get an error being thrown by WSDL. The project has a reference to Shared.DataContracts DLL. I therefore add the Service Reference by leaving the 'Re-use typres in referenced assemblies' check box ticked.

I get this error:

> Error 73  Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service
>   reference 'ServiceReference1'.  Please check other error and warning
>   messages for
>   details.  S:\src\test\source\test\Connector\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap 1   1   MetaConnector

The warning is:

> Warning   68  Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail: An
>   exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Referenced type 'Poc.Shared.DataContract.TestClass, Poc.Shared,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' with data
>   contract name 'TestClass' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Poc.Shared.DataContract'
>   cannot be used since it does not match imported DataContract. Need to
>   exclude this type from referenced types. XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IConnectorService']   S:\src\source\MetaConnector\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap 1   1   MetaConnector

If I remove  `List<TestClassTwo>` from the TestClass and replace it with just a `TestClassTwo` member it works fine. Looks like having a List is the cause of my problem.

I need to re-use the types in the shared assembly so un-checking this option is not applicable (that would remove the error though).

**EDIT: I think the visual studio 'Add Service Reference' functionality is a bit flaky based on reading around. Since I controlled both the client and server I re-factored my code to share the contract and use a `ChannelFactory` instead.
Although I did use the same contracts in a separate solution and everything seemed okay. I have a feeling the client and server solutions had some issues and they were looking at different versions of the Shared.DataContracts.DLL.**

Comment: I have tested it's working fine in my pc. there is no prob with List

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or svcutil?

Comment: @DhavalPatel - When you say tested, what do you exactly mean? You connected to the Mex Endpoint and downloaded the Metadata? This is when i get the error. When I add the service reference to my project.

Comment: I have created a service which contain the same class which you have mentioned in your question and it's working fine

Comment: I have just done the same in a brand new solution and it is fine. Something is up with both my solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding new `DataContract` like :

```
[DataContract]
public class ListTestClassTwo
{
   [DataMember]
   public List<TestClassTwo> Member { get; set; }

   public ListTestClassTwo()
   {
        Member = new List<TestClassTwo>();
   }
}
```

Then define it inside TestClass like:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
{
   [DataMember]
   public int Group { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public ListTestClassTwo ListOfMembers { get; set; }
}
```

I think this should work.

**OR Alternatively** you can try `KnownType` for `TestClassTwo` over `TestClass` like:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(TestClassTwo))]
public class TestClass
{
   [DataMember]
   public int Group { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public List<TestClassTwo> Member { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

If you are **reusing assembly** make sure **same version of assembly is referenced everywhere** it is used. Each time I faced error having `Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail`, it's always something to do with mismatch of assembly versions which  is reused.

Last time I faced similar issue it was that I added some attribute into some `DataContract` & it was reused but from where it was referenced had the old version not having new added attributes, that was the cause of issue.

Comment: @Science_Fiction, Updated answer, please make sure same version of assembly is reused.